# How to pass field attributes to a macro generating a struct

Tags: xml, rust, macros, serde

After being told ([on the quick_xml github](https://github.com/tafia/quick-xml/issues/714)) I cannot use `#[serde(flatten)]` with quick_xml and serde, I decided to emulate the behavior using a macro.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! response {
    ($($field_name: ident: $field_type: ty),*) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
        #[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
        pub struct Response {
            foobar: u32,
            $($field_name: $field_type),*
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use serde::Deserialize;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        response! {
            id: i64,
            two: i32
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_with_attribute() {
        response! {
            #[serde(rename = "foo")]
            one: i64,
            two: i32
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_with_attributes() {
        response! {
            #[serde(rename = "foo")]
            one: i64,
            #[serde(rename = "bar")]
            two: i32
        }
    }
}
```

This works great! `test::test()` runs fine, and creates the struct I want.
However, I'd like to be able to use some field attributes on the generated struct, and `test::test_with_attribute()` and `test::test_with_attributes()` both fail.

I tried using `($($(#[$field_meta: meta])* $field_name: ident: $field_type: ty),*)` for the macro signature, and this compiles for all tests; but then rust tells me

> field_meta is still repeating at this depth

when trying to use `field_meta`.

**How do you pass field attributes to a macro generating a struct?**

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06de552a6775ccf4eaae7e7e07f72259

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, That's it! If you make it an answer I'll throw you a check and an updoot for your trouble. I also feel much better knowing how close I was

Comment: To help others in the future, maybe you could also show how exactly you used field_meta that led to that error. And if the person who solved the problem doesn't create an answer as you suggested, you should create one yourself!